# FB Comments box post to wall?

Tags: facebook

I have a blog that I have a FB comment box. When I post the blog Its also sent a blurb about the blog to the fan page and then database the post id with the post.

But is it possible that when a user posts a comment in the FB comment box I can also have that post as a comment to the actual post on the fan page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the new [Social plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/) takes care of that. Let me know if it works.